# javascript paste and multiple clipboard levels

Tags: javascript, clipboard, paste, levels

After searching the Internet and doing some unsuccessful experiences trying to do paste using javascript on the Opera browser, I want to ask:

1) Is there a way I can do paste in javascript that works both on Opera and Firefox/Mozilla?

2) It would be very useful if I could reach more levels of clipboard. I explain: I use another application to copy "First text" and after "Second text". When I switch, to the browser, through some mechanism (a parameter, a variable, etc.) I could get access to the last-pasted-text, the before-the-last-pasted-text and so on. I would also like to reach the text of any clipboard level without the obligation of pasting it somewhere.
I don't know if those functionalities are possible and, for a person that is not very much into the javascript world, it seems they may be constrained to some extent by the operating system / desktop environment or even by javascript/DOM capabilities.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you have to use Flash, I don't believe you can do it with Javascript alone for all browsers. It's a little bit of a security flaw to allow access to the users clipboard.

This project does it with Flash and Javascript:

http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

For the second, I don't think this is possible. Some operating systems (or their window managers) support multiple levels of copy and paste. I seem to remember that Gnome on Ubuntu does, but not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Zeroclipboard is not available in [code.google.com](http://code.google.com)

You can access the same from [ZeroClipBoard](http://zeroclipboard.org/) website.